# Text not update onTransportControl from MediaPlayerElement (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I try to put video title on TransportControl of MediaPlayerElement like these code

**MediaTransportControlsStyle.xaml**

```
...
 <TextBlock
    Name="tblTitle"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Margin="5"
    FontFamily="Arial"
    FontSize="22"
    FontWeight="SemiBold"
    TextAlignment="Center" />
...
```

**PlayerPage.xaml.cs**

```
private async void MediaPlayer_MediaOpened(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        FrameworkElement transportControlsTemplateRoot = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(player.TransportControls, 0);
        TextBlock tblTitle = (TextBlock)transportControlsTemplateRoot.FindName("tblTitle");
        if (tblTitle != null)
            tblTitle.Text = MediaTitle; // Debug can run to this line
    });
}
```

The problem is **tblTitle** just update first time app navigate to **PlayerPage.xam**l page. From second times **tblTitle** stay blank even when debug run to the line

```
tblTitle.Text = MediaTitle; // Debug can run to this line
```

I guess I related to Dispatcher.RunAsync method to make update to UI Thread. I tried several way but no luck. How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I do not re-init MediaPlayer when go to PlayerPage. Just init everytimes and it get done